# Keeping equation into one column

Tags: equations, ieeetran, ieee-style

My document is using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`. The page is split into two equal columns. Now, when I write this equation

```
$
Weight_W = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
W_W-1 & W_W-2 & W_W-3 & ... & 1 & ... & W_W-3 & W_W-2 & W_W-1
\end{bmatrix}
$
```

it fills one column and goes into another. I need to keep into its column and in one line. 
I am very new and not much familiar with LaTeX terminology. So this question might be duplicate, but I don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Typesetting math in narrow columns is often hard; for this kind of problems there's no general solution, I'm afraid, because it depends on the material you need to typeset. Is that the whole object?

Comment: If you can remove $W_W-3$ from the formula, it is feasible.

Comment: @Bernard I just need a mathematical equation.

Comment: egreg yes, that is the whole object I need to write in a line. If that is not possible, what is usually done in this case?

Comment: Are you sure about `W_W`? Seems a bit strange.

Comment: Yes. It is okay, just like it. Why? Is it affecting something?

Answer (score 2):

You can split one long matrix into two small ones using `align*`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Weight}_W = [ &\begin{matrix} W_W-1 & W_W-2 & W_W-3 & ...\end{matrix} \\
&\begin{matrix} 1 & ... & W_W-3 & W_W-2 & W_W-1] \end{matrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: So, it isn't possible to write it in one line?

Comment: @ShuvoSarker: This is dependent on the context as @egreg said above, you can do that if you consider renaming your variables; why the repeated `W_W` all the time? are their other `W_l`, `W_n`, ..etc? isn't just `W` enough? why the long `Weight_W` as a variable name? If you answer these questions, sure you will find a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, splitting the row matrix across lines seems the only viable solution.

I'm not sure what `W_W` means, though. Naming it just `W` might seem better, but it's your paper.

Here `lipsum` is only used for providing context to the formula.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{multline*}
\mathrm{Weight}_W =
  \left[
    \begin{matrix} W_W-1 & W_W-2 & W_W-3 & \dots \end{matrix}
  \right.
\\
  \left.
    \begin{matrix} \dots & 2 & 1 & 2 & \dots & W_W-3 & W_W-2 & W_W-1 \end{matrix}
  \right]
\end{multline*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll name it `W_w`.